# Duplicate navigation property cannot be used due to single relationship error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to solve a relatively simple setup but am wondering if there is a better way to set this relation one.

I have a User class that is the starting point for all other relationships. Every other class unless specific conditions are met has a 1-to-many relationship to the User class (e.g. MenuItems is just one of them, there are other classes with the same relationship).

I have a MenuItem class that has has the UserId as the foreign key. I also want to track the user that last updated the item. But if I add the `LastUpdatedById` and `LastUpdatedBy` properties, EF core will throw an error due to the navigation property `User` participating in more than one relationship.

The whole point I was trying to solve this was when fetching the items, to include the `Created` and `LastUpdatedBy` properties so that I can easily access the user name + id. ***Is there a way to solve this or is the only option to make this a many-to-many relationship? If so, what would be the best method to accomplish that?***

The simplest option would be to make the properties string values and just update them during relevant CRUD operations but I wanted this to be a little more dynamic.

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public ICollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
    }


public class MenuItem
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public ItemType Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public int? ParentMenuItemId { get; set; }

        public MenuItem ParentMenuItem { get; set; }

        public ICollection<MenuItem> ChildMenuItems { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid LastUpdatedById { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public User LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Thanks to David for my solution. I ended up going a slightly different route based on his answer:

I created below 2 properties and deleted the original collection of MenuItem from User.

```
public ICollection<MenuItem> UpdatedMenuItems { get; set; }
public ICollection<MenuItem> CreatedMenuItems { get; set; }
```

I also used fluent API to explicitly define the relationship to make it fully defined.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItem>()
    .HasOne(x => x.CreatedBy)
    .WithMany(x => x.CreatedMenuItems)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

 modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItem>()
    .HasOne(x => x.LastUpdatedBy)
    .WithMany(x => x.UpdatedMenuItems)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.LastUpdatedById)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work you need to supress cascading deletes, and configure any inverse Navigation properties.  So something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var fks = from et in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
              from fk in et.GetForeignKeys()
              where typeof(User).IsAssignableFrom(fk.PrincipalEntityType.ClrType)
              select fk;
    foreach (var fk in fks)
    {

        fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;

    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

And then either remove the Navigation Properties on User, as there will be a ton of them, and they are perhaps not very useful, or configure them so EF knows which relationship they use.  eg in User

```
    [InverseProperty("CreatedBy")]
    public ICollection<MenuItem> CreatedMenuItems { get; set; }
```

Comment: So essentially, have 2 collection of MenuItem properties in my User class (e.g. CreatedMenuItems, UpdatedMenuItems), and then define the relationships appropriately? I.e. map FK LastUpdatedID to UpdatedMenuItems property with delete-restrict, and map FK UserId to CreatedMenuItems?

Comment: Yes.  If User has navigation properties they have to be mapped.  And User can have 0, 1, or 2 MenuItem Navigation Properties.

Comment: Thanks David. I was able to fix the issue. I did not realize that I needed to explicitly define a new property in Users to relate my duplicate navigation property in MenuItem. That fixed it. One question I had was, in the case where I did not have duplicate navigation properties, if I only had a single navigation property (i.e. CreatedBy) - do I need to explicitly define the inverse navigation in User? Per convention, the navigation property name should be named the same as the related class. Or is the one-to-many relation assumed due to the FK?

Comment: I.e. is the [InverseProperty("CreatedBy")] needed if I didn't have LastUpdatedBy and LastUpdatedById properties in my MenuItem class? Does convention already define a fully defined relationship or is that explicitly needed (due to my CreatedBy property not being called User instead?)

Comment: If there's only a single Navigation Property on each side, EF will match them up without explicit configuration.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help